# Can I run Visual Studio 2012 on a Windows 7 virtual machine?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, visual-studio

I would like to try Windows 7 before I decide to move on. The reason I'm still using XP is because of the stability and because all my programming tools work just fine with XP. However I would like to install the new Visual Studio and it requires Windows 7.

I would like to run Windows 7 as a virtual machine using Virtual PC and my question is whether it is possible to install Visual Studio inside the Windows 7 VM. I've never done it before and would like you guys to share any experiences about doing so before I dive into the install/uninstall struggle.

Answer (score 4):

You can run pretty much anything on a VM, except perhaps application that require graphic or audio acceleration (games in particular).

You can certainly run Visual Studio in a VM that supports Windows 7 like VirtualBox.

VMs are a great way to try new products or OSes. Some people also them useful simply to keep their development environment "clean" and portable.

Since you can install from a ISO image of a Windows 7 disc, it's usually quite faster than a real installation using a physical disc. And when you're done, you can delete the VM.

The main issue is going to be memory. Since XP is 32-bit, you won't be able to give Win7 more than 1.5GB or so of RAM, which is less than ideal. (Running XP VM inside a 64-bit installation of windows 7 is much easier for this reason.)

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia,

> The newest release, Windows Virtual PC, does not run on versions of Windows earlier than Windows 7

I would recommend using Virtualbox as a freeware alternative. It is rather intuitive, easy to set up, and supports the virtualization of many operating systems in addition to Windows 7. https://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: alright, is it possible to install the VS 2012 inside the Virtual box VM ? any directions. thanks

Comment: Windows 7 *should* run on Virtual PC 2007 SP1, as per this blog post: [Windows 7 on Virtual PC on Windows 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2009/01/13/windows-7-on-virtual-pc-on-windows-7.aspx) and [this answer](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverhyperv/thread/f7f87b22-13b1-433b-8a2d-7c62e3ca3542/). But yeah, VirtualBox should be a better bet if it officially supports that combo.

Comment: @joe You would install VS 2012 normally as if the VM was a physical computer.

Comment: thanks guys will try...should be easy :)...still using xp that's what i'm asking.... i'm a dinausor :)

Comment: You should also check the virtualization support for your processor. This is a handy tool: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722